# How to preserve div height with text line-breaks

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show boxes of people's names. 
The problem is that these names can get pretty long, and with a fixed width box, crazyness is sure to ensue. Long spaced text breaks, causing problems on new rows (http://jsfiddle.net/9MhWW/) and disabling line-breaks  with `white-space: nowrap;` will overflow the box (http://jsfiddle.net/9MhWW/1/).

Working with line breaks seem like the best option. If you agree, that begs the following question: Is there a way to make sure the row-problem doesn't occur without losing part of the text, having a div for every row or giving the paragraph a fixed height?

Comment: You could cut off names...

Comment: Well, maybe this is crazy solution, but if you want to have same size of divs, and not to trim any name, try http://fittextjs.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have come up with a solution. So bootstrap adds loads of stuff in to make it look nice of course, but in your case we have to undo some of that. So we have to get rid of the float left and replace it with display inline-block:

```
.span2{
    float: none !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

See the [fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/9MhWW/4/). I had to change the text alignment to match what you had previously.

Comment: @belens was that what you were after?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it! (added vertical-align:top; to finish it off). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If just one row is ok for you, set a `overflow: hidden`:

```
p { overflow: hidden; }
```

A nice effect will be using ellipsis to replace the overflowing text with `...`:

```
p { overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

See this [update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MhWW/2/).

Comment: @belens but you want all paragraphs to have the same height?

Comment: I've edited the question. I have seen ellipsis, and was planning to use it if I cannot find a way to make the page break work.

Comment: It could work for me if the box is bigger when the paragraph is, as long as the float problem doesn't occur

Comment: I see your problem. Sorry, without giving a height or changing the markup (what I would not do), I have no idea how it could work.

Comment: Linus, Martyn0627's method was what I was looking for, but your suggestions are very good alternatives. Thanks for your help!